# How do I convert a string variable to have single quotes?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a curl command that requires a link to be in single quotes, but I also want the link to be dependent on user input, so I'm using double quotes to insert a string within the link. How do I convert the LINK variable into a string with single quotes?

```
echo Enter a string
read EXAMPLE_STRING
LINK="examplewebsite.com/$EXAMPLE_STRING/somethingelse"
```

Comment: Single or double quotes only makes a difference when bash evaluates the expression to produce a string. `curl` has no idea about this. Can you show us the `curl`command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to insert in bash any special character is to put it after "\";
so for example you can use:

```
LINK=$(echo \'$LINK\')
```

or just use at you expression single quotes inside double quotes:

```
LINK="'examplewebsite.com/$EXAMPLE_STRING/somethingelse'"
```